# Ansible PUT request to update only one attribute in API data

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to update an attribute from a GET API JSON result and do a PUT request along with the entire API data with only one attribute change. Please advice on the format for PUT Req Task ?

1. Get Request for a given API call
2. From the above json data in step1, I need to update only one attribute: mipUser (From "false To "true) and do a PUT request along with the other data unchanged in the json.

I have tried using the below task for the GET. Not sure how to save the entire api result, then update the required attribute and do a POST. Probably can be done using file ?

```
- name: GET Request for CLUSTERS
      uri:
        url: https://zsapi.com/BETA/{{ item }}
        method: GET
        validate_certs: no
        return_content: yes
        status_code: 200
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
          Cookie: "{{ login.set_cookie.split(';')[0] }}"
        body_format: json
      with_items: "{{ cluster }}"
      register: cluster_result




ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "bandwidthControlApp": true,
            "cloud": "BETA",
            "createTime": 1550875210,
            "datacenter": {
                "id": 526,
                "name": "FMT1"
            },
            "description": "cluster with VIP 169.254.1.100",
            "disabled": false,
            "id": 2334,
            "lastModifiedTime": 1560896398,
            "lastModifiedUser": {
                "id": 1009,
                "name": "adev@xyz.com"
            },
            "mipUser": false,
            "mtsInstances": [],
            "name": "fmt1",
            "rateLimit": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

My expectation is entire API PUT req should be same as GET, except the attribute I'm trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correcrly, you want to udpate a variable from the return data in `msg` to some new value, and POST that to a URL in a subsequent task? If you registered the data returned as a fact, this would involve some manipulation of that fact. You can use the [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter for that.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm not able to figure out how to pass the entire json data including the new update for one of the attribute in the subsequent PUT Request Body. It would be good if you can share some example of syntax.